# Looping through a list of Java objects in JavaScript with Thymeleaf

Tags: javascript, spring-boot, thymeleaf

In a Spring Boot project, I have a list of users, in Java `List<User>`
I pass it from the Controller to the template, I am able to loop through this list using a HTML list `ul` but I am not able to do it in JavaScript:

```
<script layout:fragment="script" th:inline="javascript">
/*<![CDATA[*/
var users = /*[[${users}]]*/ [];
for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
    console.log(i); // Obviously here I would like to access the User properties
}
/*]]>*/
</script>
```

I get this error:

```
Error during execution of processor
'org.thymeleaf.standard.processor.text.StandardTextInliningTextProcessor'
```

How do we loop through lists and access Java object properties in JavaScript with Thymeleaf?
Thanks.

**EDIT: what I have discovered so far**

My User class is a JPA entity with a Country property (Country is another JPA entity):

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "country_id")
private Country country;
```

- If I pass a list of users **without the country** fetched the JavaScript works.
- If I pass a list of countries and loop through (to test the Country class by itself), it works too.
- If I pass a list of users where I set the country myself (not fetched from database) with the same values as the database contains, it works
- If I retrieve the country from the database, then set it to the user, it fails.

So it seems like the problem is because the Country entity is created/mapped to the User a certain way by Spring Data/Hibernate that Thymeleaf can not deserialize it...

Comment: try to explore ajax

Answer (score 0):

#### JavaScript natural templates

Have you got `Jackson library` in your classpath?

If you have it, It should work.

If you take a look the [reference documentation](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#javascript-inlining) it works as you are doing it:

> An important thing to note regarding JavaScript inlining is that this
>   expression evaluation is intelligent and not limited to Strings.
>   Thymeleaf will correctly write in JavaScript syntax the following
>   kinds of objects:
>
> Strings ...
>
> That ${session.user} expression will evaluate to a User object, and Thymeleaf will correctly convert it to Javascript syntax

At least, other way If you want, is configure how the Serialization is done with an instance of `StandardDialect`:

> The way this JavaScript serialization is done is by means of an
>   implementation of the
>   org.thymeleaf.standard.serializer.IStandardJavaScriptSerializer
>   interface, which can be configured at the instance of the
>   StandardDialect being used at the template engine.

As I've said before, you should have `Jackson Library` in your `classpath` (although the reference says it will have similar results I would add it):

> The default implementation of this JS serialization mechanism will
>   look for the Jackson library in the classpath and, if present, will
>   use it. If not, it will apply a built-in serialization mechanism that
>   covers the needs of most scenarios and produces similar results (but
>   is less flexible).

Finally, try to log `users` content (`console.log(users)`) to see what is doing the serialization.

#### Java mapping

Other easier way is If you want to iterate a list of java objects yous could map it to a `Json` in Java (using a library like `Jackson` or `Gson`) and then add it as parameter to the `thymeleaf template`.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String users =  mapper.writeValueAsString(users);
model.addAttribute("users", users);
```

The result of the parameter will be in a JSON format.

Comment: I have Jackson databind and core libraries in the classpath already. The thing is I pass data from controllers to templates using `Map<String, Object> model` in which I put `model.put("users", users)` are you telling me I have to serialize the map (or its content) with the `ObjectMapper`?

Comment: I say you could serialize `users`. So you would add `model.put("users", users")` once is serialized as JSON. It should work but really this is not the good way.

Comment: Yeah it's what I understood and indeed I don't want to serialize everything I put in the model. I really miss JSP/JSTL...

Comment: I edited the question, it's apparently a JPA problem